# Xamarin MediaPlayer interrupted by Android Doze Mode

Tags: android, audio, xamarin, android-doze

We have a music app (mp3) developed in Xamarin (Native Android App) using MediaPlayer. There will be list of songs that should be played one after the other. After around 10 minutes or so, the player stops. Once the phone is unlocked, the Player starts playing the next track. Seems the Nougat Doze is somehow intervening the Player. If I manually disable Battery Optimization for my app, then there is no issue.

Is there any fix for this problem rather than having each user to manually change the 'Batter Optimization' option. I wonder how other apps like Spotify plays songs continuously without any setting changes. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any process that contains a running foreground service will not be considered for Doze mode. This is what apps like Spotify and Google Play Music use. Consider creating a relevant foreground service - it will be shown in the notification screen while the foreground service is running, so a dummy service will stick out.

Another option is to request the `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` permission and then launch an `ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` intent, which will take the user to the Battery Optimization screen for your app. This is a less-than-stellar user experience but does not require the creation of a foreground service that you may not otherwise need.